# How to retrieve data from 2 join tables - accounts and aliases?

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 tables, accounts and aliases, that contain email accounts and what should be redirected to who:

```
accounts:
  id
  name
  domain_name

aliases:
  id
  source_account_id
  destination_account_id
  status
```

How can I return a destination email given a source one? I've tried this:

```
SELECT concat(ac.name, '@', ac.domain_name) as destination
FROM accounts ac

INNER JOIN aliases as al1 ON al1.source_account_id = ac.id
INNER JOIN aliases as al2 ON al2.destination_account_id = ac.id

WHERE
    concat(ac.name, '@', ac.domain_name) = '%s'
    AND al1.status = 'active' 
    AND al1.id = al2.id;
```

But it doesn't work as intended

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `account` table twice as follows:

```
SELECT concat(d.name, '@', d.domain_name) as destination
FROM accounts s
INNER JOIN aliases a ON a.source_account_id = s.id
INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS D ON a.destination_account_id = d.id
WHERE concat(s.name, '@', s.domain_name) = '%s'
  AND a.status = 'active' ;
```